# Meaning of the Matrix representation of a Linear Transformation over the space of $2\times 2$ Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the linear space of $2\times 2$ matrices and the linear tranformation $T:V \to V$ be defined as $T(X) = X + X^t$.

The matrix representation of this transformation (given the basis $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right), \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right), \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right), \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$) is

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

What I don't understand is what this representation means, since I cannot multiply a $2\times 2$ matrix by the above $4\times 4$ matrix in order to get $T(X)$. How could I use it to calculate the given linear transformation?

Comment: Vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field $\mathbb F$ is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb F^4$.

Comment: So, I could represent a $2\times 2$ matrix by a column vector with four numbers and multiply it by the given matrix representation?

Comment: Yes. This problem is a good example of what $Tv$ means for a linear transformation $T$ and a vector $v$. It is not multiplication of $T$ and $v$, it is the action of $T$ on $v$, i.e. $T(v)$.

Comment: In that case, how should I order the column vector? Should I put the columns of the matrix first, or the lines?  And why should that order be the preferred order?

Comment: It depends on how you define the isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb F^4$. This representation implies that the isomorphism is $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto (a,b,c,d)$ because for a different permutation of $a,b,c,d$, e.g. $(b,a,d,c)$ the representation of $T$ would be different (the 1st and 2nd row, and the 3rd and 4th row would swap).

Comment: It depends on the other of the basis, then? (Since the representation of $T$ depends on that order.)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the other basis, however a change of basis from the canonical one can always be incorporated into the isomorphism $V\to\mathbb F^4$, since a change of basis $\mathbb F^4\to\mathbb F^4$ is itself an isomorphism, so we would have a composition of two isomorphisms $V\to\mathbb F^4\to\mathbb F^4$, which is again an isomorphism.